# '0200: Failure Fixed Disk 0' when installing new SSD on Samsung Netbook

Tags: boot, ssd, netbook

I am trying to install a **Samsung CM871a 2.5''** SSD on my old **Samsung N210plus netbook**.

When booting, it says:
**0200: Failure Fixed Disk 0**

When I try to install Windows 7 or 10, it says:
**Ensure that disk controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu**

The SSD does work as an external harddrive when I connect it to USB via a USB-SATA cable.

I have tried the following solutions, but these do not fix the problem:

- Bios:

  - Make sure UEFI is active and not corrupted.
  - SATA should be set on AHCI mode.
  - On the Security Tab, look for a Secure / Safe Boot option and disable that option

Does anyone know of a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The disk might be incompatible.

Comment: I turned out that the SSD was indeed incompatible, I tried it with another one, and this one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this SSD was indeed incompatible, I tried it with a brand new one:

**Kingston A400 2,5" 480GB**

and this one works perfectly with my netbook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just mark your answer as answered waiting two days ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It has been 8 months, Did you have any luck fixing your SSD?

> SATA should be set on AHCI mode.

In bios Try to change The AHCI to IDE if available! This worked with some.

### I Have the same problem!

Currently Iam facing the same issue, NEW ***SAMSUNG*** SSD on older devices, An Acer Aspire 4720 laptop & a core2duo Desktop (American Mega trends BIOS)
On laptop I get
0200: Failure Fixed Disk 0.
While Desktop gives beeps then a simple
(Slave/MASTER depending on SATA port) "DISK ERROR"
On the desktop When booting to windows I need to assign a letter to explore it. (It runs fine but not a bootable SSD)
**HOWEVER**,
On my 4th Gen thinkpad it boots no problem!

### Steps Taken

1. Took out the **working** Kingspec SSD (Chinese SATA 3) from Acer laptop then inserted Samsung SSD (Didn't appear in BIOS)
2. SSD was initialized to MBR connected through an External closure. (*as its intended purpose was to be installed on Acer.*)
3. Installed on Laptop (Noticed *0200: Failure Disk*)
4. Tried Windows CMD Shift+F10 from the DVD installation media
5. Using Diskpart I cleaned the SSD, Partitioned, formatted & assigned a letter.
6. Refreshed the list to have the same *Ensure that disk controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu*

Maybe Windows 10 initialized it wrong?
MAYBE Samsung SSD controller have bad backwards compatibility with older SATA controllers!?

I'll look for Gparted or BootICE methods as options but for now..
Best of luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).